# Which USB controller is device plugged into on ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, usb, controller, passthrough

I need to pass through a USB controller (not just the USB device) to a guest on an ESXi 6.7 host.  Is there a way (without trial and error) to determine which controller a device is plugged into?

So if I wanted to pass through the controller which connects to "Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec" how would I know what to pass through?

```
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0471:485e Philips (or NXP) 
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 08bb:2902 Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1b1c:1c08 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 223b:0005  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0658:0200 Sigma Designs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8002 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:800a Intel Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```